# Django filters with a string variable field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to filter a model with a field but I want to pass the field as a string variable. How can I do it?

For example:

```
the_field = 'name'
TheModel.objects.filter(the_field='Gazelle')
```

What should I replace *the_field* with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *dictionary unpacking*:

```
the_field = 'name'
TheModel.objects.filter(**{the_field: 'Gazelle'})
```

Notice the two asterisks (`**`) in front of the dictionary. If you call a function with `f(**{'a': 4})`, that is equivalent to calling it with `f(a=4)`.

or you can make use of a `Q` object, and pass it a 2-tuple that represents the key and value:

```
from django.db.models import Q
the_field = 'name'
TheModel.objects.filter(Q((the_field, 'Gazelle')))
```